# Selecting options in angular-ui type ahead has no effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the html markup:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="typeAheadTemplate.html">
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.model.PROJECT_DESC | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
</script>

<div ng-show="commentMain.commentType == 'project'" id="commentProjectOther" 
                       class="btn-group animate-slide-vertical" style="margin-bottom: 7px; margin-left: 7px;">
    <input type="text" ng-model="commentMain.project" placeholder="Select the name of the project" 
                       typeahead-on-select="commentMain.comment.PROJECT_ID = $model.PROJECT_ID || null"
                       typeahead="project for projects in commentMain.getProjects($viewValue)" 
                       typeahead-loading="loadingProjects"
                       typeahead-template-url="typeAheadTemplate.html" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

projects are coming back as `[{PROJECT_DESC: 'Blah', PROJECT_ID: 1, ...other params}, etc.]`

The API is being accessed and options are being populated into the type-ahead.

However, the type ahead is not letting me select any of the options. What I mean is that when I hover over the options, they do not turn blue and when I select an option it does not populate the model (or the type ahead textbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they do not turn blue because you used your own template for typeahead, if you just want to show the project description in the typeahead remove the `typeahead-template-url` and change the typeahead attribute to:

```
typeahead="project as project.PROJECT_DESC for projects in commentMain.getProjects($viewValue)"
```

And your on-select is wrong too, should be:

```
typeahead-on-select="commentMain.comment.PROJECT_ID = commentMain.project.PROJECT_ID"
```

because you defined `commentMain.project` as your model and when you select one project this will be populated!